# Ordenar data pelo mês

Tags: sql, sql-server

No desenvolvimento de uma query, estou a ter um problema de ordenação dos meses. Por exemplo, no gráfico aparecem-me primeiro Abril, depois Janeiro, Junho, Agosto... E o que eu queria obter, era a ordem desses mesmos meses, 1º Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março...

**Query**

```
Set Language 'Portuguese'
SELECT DateName(mm,DataEntrada) as DataEntrada, COUNT(ID_Reserva) TotalReservas 
From Reserva 
group by DateName(mm,DataEntrada) 
Order by DataEntrada
```

Comment: Pode colocar exemplos das datas? Se o campo "DataEntrada" é um campo data deveria mostrar corretamente, ou são meses de anos diferentes?

Comment: Os dados mensais devem ser somados sem se considerar a possibilidade de que existam dados de mais de um ano para um mesmo mês?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função **MONTH** para te retornar o mês da sua data e ordenar pelo retorno da função, a query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DateName(mm,DataEntrada) as DataEntrada, 
       COUNT(ID_Reserva) TotalReservas 
FROM Reserva
GROUP BY DateName(mm, DataEntrada), MONTH(DataEntrada)
ORDER BY MONTH(DataEntrada)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou na perfeição !

Answer (score 1):

Você vai ter que adicionar a data em formato numérico na cláusula `group by`. Somente desta forma você vai conseguir criar uma ordenação por Mês e não pela palavra associada ao Mês, desta forma:

```
Set Language 'Portuguese' 

SELECT DateName(mm,DataEntrada) as MesExtenso, COUNT(ID_Reserva) TotalReservas 
From Reserva 
group by  DateName(mm,DataEntrada) ,datepart(mm,DataEntrada)
Order by datepart(mm,DataEntrada)
```

Veja funcionando no  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9b5f0/10)

Comment: Já encontrei a solução, no entanto, agradeço imenso a sua boa vontade em me tentar ajudar !